Workbox SW keep requests with error in queue
I'm using the workbox-background-sync plugin to queue POST requests when users are offline, with the following setup:
const postSyncPlugin = new BackgroundSyncPlugin('post-requests', {
  maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60,
})

registerRoute(
  ({request}) => request.url.includes('example.com'),
  new NetworkOnly({
    plugins: [postSyncPlugin],
  }),
  'POST',
)

When the connection is restored, some of these POST requests may return an error (response.status >= 400). I'd like to retain these failed requests in the queue so that users can manage them (i.e., modify the payload and manually re-trigger sync). To achieve this, I’m using IndexedDB to list the queued requests and allow user control.
Based on the Workbox example (statusPlugin), I understand that throwing an error should trigger the fetchDidFail callback, causing the request to remain in the queue until the next sync event. However, I’m seeing that all queued requests, including those with 200 and 400 status codes, are removed from the queue upon sync.
I tried replacing BackgroundSyncPlugin with the Queue approach, but the behavior didn’t change:
const PostsQueue = new Queue('post-requests')

const bgSync: WorkboxPlugin = {
  fetchDidFail: async ({request}) => {
    console.log('fetchDidFail called')
    await PostsQueue.pushRequest({request})
  },
  
  fetchDidSucceed: async ({response}) => {
    if (response.status >= 400) {
      console.log('fetchDidSucceed called')
      const body = await response.json()
      throw new Error(`Server error. ${JSON.stringify(body)}`)
    }

    return response
  },
}

Both fetchDidSucceed and fetchDidFail are logged, but the queue is cleared afterward.
As an alternative, I tried using a temporary queue for failed requests and re-adding them when the main queue is empty, but this approach was complex and didn't work. I’m unsure if I need to override the default onSync method.
Is there something I’m missing, or is a custom onSync method necessary to retain failed requests in the queue?
Thank you
Note: Not really sure if it matters but I am using React and the requests are done using fetch

Found a fix that fits my requirements. Not really sure if it s the perfect one, but for the moment it does what I am looking for.
I have created a new Queue with forceSyncFallback: true, so no auto sync,
and when a request with status >= 400 happens, it goes to the newly created queue as it follows
const failedPostQueue = new Queue('failed-post-requests', {
  forceSyncFallback: true,
})

const postSyncPlugin = new BackgroundSyncPlugin('post-requests', {
  maxRetentionTime: 24 * 60,
  onSync: async ({queue}) => {
    let entry
    while ((entry = await queue.shiftRequest())) {
      try {
        const response = await fetch(entry.request.clone())

        if (response.status >= 400) {
          await failedPostQueue.pushRequest({
            request: entry.request.clone(),
            metadata: {
              response: await response.json(),
            },
          })
        }
      } catch (error) {
        await queue.unshiftRequest(entry)
      }
    }
  },
})

It is still work in progress, but looks good for the moment. If there is a better approach I would be really happy to try it.
